# How to mount usb drive in nexus 5 using mount command?

Tags: usb, nexus-5, permissions, mount, usb-on-the-go

I read in some online sources that lolipop 5 allows mounting usb devices using otg cable without root permissions.

Another thing i saw is that the app "ES Explorer" can mount usb devices without root.

I'm trying to mount usb device using the built in "mount" command but im recieving "permissions denied" error.

The device shows in /etc/partitions as:

```
8    0    15633408    sda
8    1    15633392    sda1
```

I tried

```
mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

and get "permission denied"

What is the right way to mount usb device?

How does ES Explorer mount usb device without root permissions?